# Access inherited method during construction of base class?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a weird C++ problem where I'm not sure if it works correctly this way or If I missed something.

There is a class `A` which inherits from `ABase`. `ABase` and `A` both have a method `Generate()` while `A::Generate()` should overwrite `ABase::Generate()`.

Generate() is called out of the constructor of ABase.

Now my problem:

I do a `new A()` which first jumps into constructor of A and from there into constructor of ABase. `ABase::ABase()` now calls `Generate()`. What I want to do: `A::Generate()` should be executed (since this overwrites `ABase::Generate()`).

Unfortunately it seems out of the constructor of `ABase` only `ABase::Generate()` is called and never `A::Generate()`.

I gues that happens because A is not fully constructed at this stage? Or is there a way to let `ABase::ABase()` make use of `A::Generate()`?

Comment: Instead of describing the code, can you please post it instead?

Comment: There is no easy way out: virtual methods should not be called from constructors or destructors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Of course you can call virtual functions, and it works exactly like it works anywhere else.  The function called depends on the dynamic type of the object.  Which, during construction, is the type of the constructor currently running.

Comment: @andre If you mean using the strategy pattern, that's the usual solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do *not* want `A::Generate()` to be executed, since this
would involve executing a function on a class which has not been
constructed.  C++ has been designed intentionally so that during
construction, the dynamic type of the object is the type being
constructed, precisely to avoid this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to work around, and definitely not pretty, but you may be able to do something like this:

```
class ABase
{
public:
    ABase()
    {
        // Normal constructor, calls `Generate`
    }

    virtual void Generate() { ... }

    // ...

protected:
    struct do_not_call_generate_tag {};

    const static do_not_call_generate_tag do_not_call_generate;

    ABase(const do_not_call_generate_tag)
    {
        // Same as the normal `ABase` constructor, but does _not_ call `Generate`
    }
};

class A : public ABase
{
public:
    A()
        : ABase(ABase::do_not_call_generate)
    {
        // Other initialization
        PrivateGenerate();
    }

    void Generate()
    {
        PrivateGenerate();
    }

private:
    void PrivateGenerate()
    {
        // Do what your old `Generate` does
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have nicely constructed *and* initialized objects, I would separate these two tasks from each other:

```
class ABase
{
public:
    virtual void Generate()
    {
        //...
    }
};

class A: public ABase
{
public:
    virtual void Generate()
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

Now you have to perform both tasks explicitly

```
A *someA = new A();
someA->Generate();
```

...but you can group this inside e.g. a `Create()` method or redefine the `new` operator or the like.